# Delphi - Android - Saving textfile to internal storage

Tags: android, delphi, save, text-files, internal-storage

I'm pretty new to Android development.
I want to develop an App, that is able to save a text file on the internal storage (in the App's private folder or something like that).

I have following code:

```
    procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      tstrTmp: TStringList;
      sFn: String;
    begin
      tstrTmp := TStringList.Create;
      tstrTmp.Text := 'Test';
      sFn := Format( '%s/Test.txt', [GetHomePath ]);
      sFn := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'Test.txt';
      sFn := TPath.Combine( System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath , 'Test.txt' );
      tstrTmp.SaveToFile( sFn );
      tstrTmp.Free;
      showmessage( sFn );
    end;
```

When I run the App and click the button, it is showing me: '/data/user/0/com.embarcadero.[MyAppName]/files/Test.txt'.
So, I would assume that the file was physically written to that location.

But when I connect my device to my pc, I can't even find this folder.
I also searched on the external storage but I was not able to find this folder or file (Test.txt).

I did found a folder on my internal storage : /Android/data/com.embarcadero.[MyAppName]/files, but no file in there.

so, I'm a bit stuck here, because I would assume the file is saved somewhere.
But I'm not able to find it.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks for your feedback.

Best Regards,

Wim.

Comment: Just a quick guess: Your app should probably create the directory if it doesn't already exists.

Comment: Does you app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions?

Comment: You do not need any permission and the directory is already there. On your PC only Android Studio/Delphi can show you that location and i am not shure about Delphi. Also file manager apps on your device will not show you this directory as they have no access to your apps private folder.

Comment: You can -with code- check if a file exist. And you can read that file for further use. Do it and you will see.

Comment: `GetHomePath`/`TPath.GetDocumentsPath` is private to your app, it is not exposed to other apps or the PC. If you want to make a file accessible to them, it needs to be created in a public folder instead, like `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath`. Also, just FYI, last time I checked (albeit that was a long while ago), FireMonkey did a pretty lousy job of reporting errors for various operations, like creating files, so more times than not you wouldn't know if such operations actually succeeded or failed.

Comment: @fpiette: I already tried to create the folder manually (from my Windows Explorer when device is connected to my pc). And you also asked about the permission (RED/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). but i want the file on the internal storage (because I 'm not sure all the devices will have an external storage).

Comment: @blackapps: I'm sure the file is physically created, because I can open the file from source code and get the content of it in a variable. Only thing is that I was not able to find the file using my Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I will try to use your suggestion. But today I will not have time to test it. So I will get back with feedback once I have tested out your suggestion. thanks to everybody already for your comments.

Comment: Hi all,
I finally had  some time now to try out the suggestion of Remy Lebeau.  Using the TPath.GetDocumentsPath did not showed me the file in the folder on the device (from my Windows Explorer).  I then tried with TPath.GetPublicPath. Still no success.  Finally I changed the App-Permissions, and allow 'Storage' option (Settings - Apps - <MyApp> - Permissions - set Storage as Active).  By doing this, the app was able to store the file on my device location at: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<AppName>/files.  So the rootcause was not in the app, but n the Android Settings of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution was:
Set the App-Permisisons for Storage (Settings - Apps - MyApp - Permission - Storage).

Once this was done, using the TPath.GetPublicPath to store the file resulted in a file on the Device (Internal Storage) on: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files
Where '/storage/emulated/0' = the rootfolder of the internal storage of my device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have concern if the internal root path changes between devices you can try this

```
AppPath := ReplaceStr(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath,'/Download','');
```

will give you what you want so you don't have to worry if it is '/storage/emulated/0' or something else.